# Why is my lemon verbena growing flat?

Tags: containers, herbs

My container-planted lemon verbena is growing nicely and providing a lot of green leaves, however, it keeps growing very flat instead of tall, to the point that the branches often touch the ground.

Is there something I can do, a way to prune it or something, to get it to grow taller and stronger?

[image]

[image]

Comment: how much sun does it get?

Comment: About 6-8 hours a day. It's facing west so from early noon till sunset more or less.